# Rails 5: Cron jobs using Whenever not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I am trying to make a task run every hour using the Whenever gem.

```
#check_price.rake
namespace :check_price do
  desc "TODO"
  task check_now: :environment do
    price_sync = PriceSyncLibrary.new
    Product.all.each do |product|
      product.price.push(price_sync.get_price_from_link(product.flipkart_link))
      product.time.push(Time.now)
      product.save!
    end
  end  
end
```

This is my schedule.rb file

```
every 1.minute do
  rake "check_price:check_now", environment: 'development' 
end
```

When I run

```
rake check_price:check_now
```

in the terminal, I am getting the result I want, but the same rake task is not running every minute as specified in the schedule.rb file. Am I missing something?

When I run

```
crontab -l
```

in the console, I get this result.

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/raghav/workspace/apps/Shotgun/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/raghav/workspace/apps/Shotgun && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake check_price:check_now --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/raghav/workspace/apps/Shotgun/config/schedule.rb

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: Shotgun
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/raghav/workspace/apps/Shotgun && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake check_price:check_now --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: Shotgun
```

Comment: Can you show what is in the users crontab file?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with this information, this is unreadable.

Comment: Try running the command in the crontab at the command line without the silent flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schedule.rb file, your environment is set to development and in the response of crontab -l command the environment is set to production,
You can set the environment like this,

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minute do
  rake "check_price:check_now"
end
```